# Find part of value in dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, search

I have the following dictionary:

```
["uno" : "unoValue", "dos" : "dosValue", "tres" : "tresValue"]
```

I need to do a each of the keys that contain certain characters. For example if I look for 'no' I would only get key "uno" because of the "u*NO*Value". If I look for 'val' I would get all three keys.

I would need to get all the keys in an array such as ["uno"] and ["uno","dos","tres"] for the second case.

I am new at swift but I am building a dummy app for a search and I have no idea how to do this. If you have any other ideas for the search function I will also accept them gratefully.

Comment: Is your question about Python or Swift? If it is about only one of them, please delete the other tag. If it is about both, please [edit] your question to make that clear.

Comment: All keys: `dct.keys()`. Key's containing no: `[x for x in dct.keys() if "no" in x]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dict = ["uno" : "unoValue", "dos" : "dosValue", "tres" : "tresValue"]

let searchTerm = "val"
let keys = Array(
    dict.keys.filter { dict[$0]!.range(of: searchTerm, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil }
)

print(keys)
```

How it works:

- `dict.keys.filter` filter all the keys in the dictionary meeting a certain condition
- `dict[$0]!.range(of: searchTerm, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil` checks the value that it contains the search term
- `Array( ... )` converts it to an array of strings, otherwise it's a `LazyFilterCollection`

Comment: Why do you put that expression through the array initializer?

Comment: @Alexander The OP asked for an array of keys meeting the condition. Without that, it remains a `LazyFilterCollection`

Comment: True. I think it's worth mentioning that it might not be necessary to have an Array. For example, if OP only want to iterate over those keys, it can remain a `LazyFilterCollection`

Comment: Btw. you can filter a dictionary directly, like so: `dict.filter {_, value in value.range(of: searchTerm, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil }.map{$0.key}`. It prevents the need for hash look ups and unwraps that `dict[$0]!` causes.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"uno" : "unoValue", "dos" : "dosValue", "tres" : "tresValue"}
search_term = "Val"
list = [] 
for key, value in dict.items():
    if search_term in value:
        list.append(key)
print (list)
```

Answer (score 0):

my Playground sample:

```
import Foundation

let dict = ["uno" : "unoValue", "dos" : "dosValue", "tres" : "tresValue"]


let searchTerm = "val"

var result = dict.filter { 
    $0.value.range(of: searchTerm, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil
}.map{$0.key}


print(result) // ["tres", "uno", "dos"]
```